# How to use CSS to change font color of emptyText

Tags: rally

I am using a non-editable objectPicker and setting the empty text:

```
     this.statePicker = Ext.create('Rally.ui.picker.MultiObjectPicker', { 
            modelType: 'State',
            id: 'statePicker',
            matchFieldWidth: false,
            editable:false,        
            emptyText: "Select...",
            placeholderText: "Select...",
            width: 80,
            listeners: {                
                select: this._getFilter,
                deselect: this._getFilter,
                scope: this
            },  
        });
```

I want to format the emptyText (emptyText: "Select...",) to be white with a background color. Using the below CSS, the background color displays perfectly, but the text color stays gray.

```
.x-form-empty-field {
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
  background-color: #085478;  
}
```

Ihave tried other classes but none change the font. It stays gray! Please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'emptyText' is applied to the field using the 'placeholder' HTML5 attribute.  The answer is going to vary depending on which browser you are using.

Here is a guide that demonstrates how to style the placeholder text in the various browsers that support it: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-placeholder-text/

Here is some useful information about the placeholder attribute in general (also includes styling examples): http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/html5-placeholder/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was not aware of the placeholder attribute which solved my problem!